# Vertically center inline-blocks elements in header

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design

In a header top banner:

```css
#header { background-color: #eaeaea; } 
#header a { display: inline-block; margin-right: 1.5em;  }
.logo { margin-right: 6em; }
```

```html
<div id="header">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x120" class="logo">
<a href="">Lorem</a>
<a href="">Ipsum</a>
<a href="">Contact</a>
</div>
```

what are the main methods used nowadays to center the 3 right links vertically inside the banner?

I know how to do it with `position: relative; top:-...px` or similar methods or even `<table>`, but what would be considered nowadays as the most appropriate methods, especially for responsive design?

Would you use `flex` features for this? If so, how?

I also want stick the group of 3 links to the right border of the screen, such that, if we resize the browser width, it always stays floating along the right border. I was about to use `float: right` but there's probably a better solution than mixing `flex` and `float`?

PS: These last details are not in the linked questions [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically) and [How to Vertical align elements in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/how-to-vertical-align-elements-in-a-div), thus it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnaly i would use **flex** with `align-items:center` for responsive design.

**See the code below**:

```css
#header{ 
  background-color: #eaeaea; 
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
} 
#header a{ 
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
.logo{
  margin-right: 6em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x120" class="logo">
  <div id="links">
    <a href="">Lorem</a>
    <a href="">Ipsum</a>
    <a href="">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks @KevRob. Would you know how to stick the group of 3 links to the right border of the screen, such that, if we resize the browser width, it always stays floating along the right border? Is this possible while keeping `flex`? I was about to use `float: right` but there's probably a better solution than mixing `flex` and `float`?

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of solutions. I would put the links within a div with `display:flex` as well and add this css to the '#header': `justify-content : space-between`. Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Wonderful @KevRob, it works; I edited your answer to include it, it's perfect now!

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to vertical centering of text and items, this trick comes in handy:

```css
#header {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

A more reliable (albiet complicated) method is to use a grid wrapper

```css
.center {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-areas: 'a b c';
   grid-template-rows: 1fr max-content 1fr;
}
.center > * {
   grid-area: b
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x120" class="logo">
  <a class="center" href=""><span>Lorem</span></a>
  <a class="center" href=""><span>Ipsum</span></a>
  <a class="center" href=""><span>Contact</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you know @HarrisonSmith how to stick the group of 3 links to the right border of the screen, such that, if we resize the browser width, it always stays floating along the right border? Is this possible while keeping `flex`? I was about to use `float: right` but there's probably a better solution than mixing `flex` and `float`?

Comment: @Basj What do you mean by "groups" I only see one group of 3 links there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about old browsers (IE), you can use `place-items`, instead of `align-items`.

```css
#header{ 
  background-color: #eaeaea; 
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
} 
#header a{ 
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
.logo{
  margin-right: 6em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x120" class="logo">
  <a href="">Lorem</a>
  <a href="">Ipsum</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Quoting from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items:

> The CSS place-items shorthand property allows you to align items along both the block and inline directions at once (i.e. the align-items and justify-items properties) in a relevant layout system such as Grid or Flexbox. If the second value is not set, the first value is also used for it.